# How to get api names and their value from list

Tags: list

Can anyone please help me with following issue

I am having a list of opportunity contains 3 fields value for opportunity.

```
List<opportunity>  listopp = new List<opportunity>( );
listopp.realdata__c = 'value1';
listopp.realdata__c = 'value2';
finalList.add(listopp);
Insert finalList;
```

Now from finalList how I can get the api name of values saved in it for each record. And can save it in map.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you are looking for way to get API name of the fields populated in your Opportunity record.

```
Opportunity opp=new Opportunity(Name='Pikachu',Stage='CLosed');

System.debug(opp.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().keySet()); // Prints [Name,Stage]
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap